# Put labels on Kendo Switch

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui

I am using the Switch Component from Kendo UI for Angular. I created a switch component, but I noticed that in the Documentation the switch appears with default labels "On" and "Off" [default switch](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/switch/), but my Button appeared without them. So I went to the documentation and saw the "offLabel" and "onLabel" [properties](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/api/SwitchComponent/). I used them in my code but I still don't get labels.

component.html

```
<kendo-switch name="isActive" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" class="switch" [(ngModel)]="inspectionPlan.isActive"></kendo-switch>
```

I opened the Browser DevTools and saw this

```
<span class="k-switch-label-on" aria-hidden="true"> Yes </span>
<span class="k-switch-label-off" aria-hidden="true"> Yes </span>
```

I think the labels don't appear, because of the aria-hidden property, but I don't understand why it's set by default to be hidden. Does anyone know how to remove it?

Comment: Do you have the kendo css imported correctly? Styles over riding it?

Comment: what do you mean with kendo css? I wrote my css code in the scss file that gets created automatically when i create a new component.

Comment: Which Kendo theme are you using? For me, the Bootstrap theme hides the text and I had to override it.

Comment: Kendo's getting started guide should have you choose a style, and import it for the application. *edit* If you aren't importing one, that could be the problem. If you are, it might be one without the attributes you want

Answer (score 1):

Some kendo themes seem to hide the labels, while the default theme shows them...

This CSS is what I use to show the labels:

```
.k-switch.k-switch-md {
  width: 4.5rem;
}
   
.k-switch-label-off, .k-switch-label-on {
    display: inline;
    width: calc(100% - 2em - 12px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-shadow: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.k-switch-label-on {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: left;
  left: 8px;
}
.k-switch-label-off {
  color: #333;
  text-align: right;
  right: 8px;
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/okOZEjaD)**